# how to create event calendar in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react native. i am working on a project in which i wanted to create a calendar (monthly, weekly, day) in which i can add event to a particular date. I have gone through some of the built-in npm plugins. https://www.newline.co/@dmitryrogozhny/how-to-add-month,-week,-or-day-calendar-in-react-with-fullcalendar--7e10e8cf is this the link works as per my requirement i need suggestion or any help. As i am confused that this plugin would work or not.
Mock up:
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i can make you one total custom one :)

Answer (score 0):

There is [big calendar](https://github.com/llotheo/react-native-big-calendar) already.

Comment: Thank you for your instant reply but it is only for day. monthly and weekly calendars are not there.